# Exporting Multiple MS Access Forms to A Single PDF File

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to output multiple forms to a pdf file with the following code in Access:

```
Public Function Print_Form()
Dim myPath, reportName As String


        For Each r In gvParent_Vals 
            glParent_id = r 
            If giMsgBox = 1 Then

//this method opens the form and makes it the active object
                Select_Form 

//set file path and pdf file to send form to
                myPath = "C:\Users\C062342\Desktop\"
                reportName = "test.pdf"

//output page 1 of the form              
                DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "Frm_Main_Report", acFormatPDF, myPath & reportName, False

// set global variable to page 2 source form and specify target to replace (subform of page 1 form)

                gsActiveForm = "Frm_Main_Report_Pg2"  
                 Set goCurrForm = Forms![Frm_Main_Report].Form.[Frm_Main_Report_Pg1]

//method to set the page 2 form by setting the target equal to the new source object

                 Activate_Form

//send page 2 to the same pdf file

                DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "Frm_Main_Report", acFormatPDF, myPath & reportName, False

//method to Close the form
                Close_Form

            End If
        Next r

 End Function
```

When I do this in a loop I only get the very last form that opens, as if when Access is sending each form to the PDF file it is overwriting the last one each time. The other problem is that I need to output the form in landscape and I'm not sure how get this to happen in the PDF file. Are there any settings that go with this method or code that would precede or follow it that would allow me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible. Access cannot append to an existing PDF.

`DoCmd.OutputTo` with an existing PDF file will overwrite that file.

The best course of action is to create a report that contains all data you want to export.

Or: use an external PDF printer driver that has multi-document capabilities, i.e. you create several print jobs from Access, and the driver combines them into one PDF file.
Example: http://freepdfxp.de/index_en.html

But this will a manual operation, unless you find a driver that can be fully automated.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  Would it be possible to append into a Word document or some other kind of rich text file that I could then manually convert to a PDF all in one shot?

Comment: I should also say that I agree with you on the report route; however, I am rendering some of the data in the form with VBA as the form gets run, so I was running into problems setting control values in a report this way whereas the form does not give me any problems in doing this.

Comment: @Scott: 1. No. 2. in reports, you need to put the vba code in the section (usually Detail section) `On Format` event.

Comment: Ah of course...that makes complete sense now.  Brilliant..Thank you!